# Combinatorial proof of binomial coefficient summation

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, proof-writing

While doing some Computer Science problems, I found one which I thought could be solvable using combinatorics instead of programming:

*Given two positive integers $n$ and $k$, in how many ways do $k$ numbers, all of which are between $0$ and $n$ (inclusive), add up to $n$?*

In the problem, order does matter. For example, 0+20 is not equivalent to 20+0. This led me to the following solution:

Assume you do want to create the sum without any of the terms being zero. Then, the problem can be looked at as if you have $n$ rocks, and you want know the number of ways you can place $k-1$ sticks between them, such that no stick may be placed between the same two rocks. This is obviously equal to $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

If you then want to count the number of ways you can create the sum with *exactly one* of the terms being zero. Then the solution is (number of ways to get to $n$ using $k-1$ non-zero terms)*(the number of ways we can choose 1 element among k). Then, when wanting to count the number of ways with *exactly $x$* zeroes, the answer is (number of ways to get to n using $k-x$ non-zero terms)*(the number of ways we can choose $x$ elements among $k$).

The solution to the original problem will basically the sum of the above expression, with x ranging between $0$ and $k-1$ (since there needs to be at least 1 non-zero term).

This leads to
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left[ \binom{n-1}{k-i-1}\binom{k}{i}\right]$

I later went on to search on Google if there existed any simpler solution, and found that $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ worked as well, but without explanation and proof.

Both solutions give the same answer for any positive $n$ and $k$, but I really have trouble understanding why. I've tried to simplify my summation, and proving it inductively, but I have not been successful.

Could somebody help me prove the equality?

$\binom{n+k-1}{n} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left[ \binom{n-1}{k-i-1}\binom{k}{i}\right]$

Comment: Hint: Find instead the number of ways of dividing $n+k$ into $k$ parts, all $\ge 1$.

Comment: That was a really nice solution too, and a bit more mathematical I suppose. :-)

Comment: [*Very* related...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: Your final equation is an example of Vandermonde's identity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: @Byron - cool, even an algebraic proof there!

Comment: @J.M - aww, I thought I were the first to use that analogy... :)

Comment: At this late an age, you should be genuinely surprised when you come up with something that's actually new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to break into cases concerning the existence of piles of "0 rocks".  A pile of zero rocks can be represented by having two "sticks" between the same two rocks (between those two sticks there are zero rocks!).  Indeed, I can represent any number of consecutive piles of zero rocks by having the appropriate number of sticks between the same two rocks.

So, with that in mind, I am really looking to count the number of ways that I can place $k-1$ sticks among $n$ rocks.  (By the way, why does this representation still retain the ordering?  Try finding sticks and rocks representations of $0 + 20$ and $20 + 0$, and other combinations.)  Now, this is equivalent to choosing from $n + k - 1$ objects, exactly $n$ of them to be our "rocks" (leaving the other $k-1$ to be our "sticks").  And there are $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ ways to do that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: By the way, your piecewise identity can be written as a single formula!  What happens when $n = 1$?  In the summation, there is a binomial coefficient with $n-1 = 0$ on the top, which evaluates to $0$ unless the bottom is also $0$ (in which case, $\binom{0}{0} = 1$), which occurs only when $k - i - 1 = 0$, or $i = k-1$.  But then the second factor would be $\binom{k}{i} = \binom{k}{k-1} = k$.  The sum is exactly equal to $k$ when $n = 1$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Makes sense now that you say it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, of course 0 choose 0 = 1. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your rocks and sticks example, your basic question is how many ways are there to place $n$ rocks and $k-1$ sticks in order as each pattern (of the rocks) is one solution to your problem.  This is ${n+k-1 \choose n}$.

If $n=1$ then all your discussion of $i$ zero terms will come out at $0$ except when $i=k-1$ and in that case you will have  $\left[ \binom{0}{0}\binom{k}{k-1}\right] = k$, so you do not need to distinguish $n=1$ in your expression.